# Passing JSON data from HTTP request to another view controller in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift

How to pass the JSON data from HTTP request to another view controller in swift 3? This function is when selected a cell, It will get the JSON data from server then I have to pass the JSON data to another view controller.

```
func retrieveTime(jobDateValue: String) -> Void {
    if let crew = user!["crew"] as? [String:Any], let crewID = crew["crew_id"] as? String{

        let param = ["action": "retrieve time", "job": ["crew_id": crewID, "jobDate": jobDateValue]] as [String : Any]

        let headers = [
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        ]

        if let postData = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])) {

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://52.221.231.3/gv/app_api.php")!,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData

            _ = URLSession.shared

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                    (data, response, error) -> Void in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [.mutableContainers])) as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        let result = json["result"] as? String

                        if (result == "success") {
                            let passValue = json
                        }else{

                        }
                    }
                })
            }

            task.resume()
        }

    }

}
```

passing json data to second view controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SecondVCSegue"{
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SecondVC {
            destination.passedData = json
        }
    }
}
```

JSON Output:

```
{
    jobs =     (
                {
            jobDate = "2017-09-01";
            jobEndTime = 1504231200;
            jobID = 88;
            jobTime = 1504224000;
        }
    );
    message = "Retrieve Sucessfully";
    result = success;
}
```

Comment: What is not working with your current code? How is your segue defined? Some general advice: `_ = URLSession.shared` this does nothing, get rid of it. Also don't use Foundation data types, when they have native Swift equivalents, use `var request = URLRequest(...` instead of `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor The segue is not working. I don't know how to pass all the json data to another view controller. I tried google it, but all the question is about passing a single string (textlabel.text!).

Comment: How is the segue set up, what is it connected to exactly on your Storyboard?

Comment: @DávidPásztor It is a static table cell and I set push (deprecated segue) to second view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set up a manual segue in `Storyboard`, that you only call inside the completion handler of your network request. If the segue is connected to a single tableview cell, it will be called by the system before your async function would finish execution. Once you changed your segue to be manual and not connected to a static table view cell, you can call it using the function `performSegue`.

```
func retrieveTime(jobDateValue: String) -> Void {
    if let crew = user!["crew"] as? [String:Any], let crewID = crew["crew_id"] as? String{
        let param = ["action": "retrieve time", "job": ["crew_id": crewID, "jobDate": jobDateValue]] as [String : Any]
        let headers = [ "content-type": "application/json", "cache-control": "no-cache" ]

        if let postData = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])) {
            var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://52.221.231.3/gv/app_api.php")!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                guard error == nil, let data = data else {return}
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String:Any]{
                        let result = json["result"] as? String
                        if (result == "success") {
                            let passValue = json
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegue", sender: json)
                        } else{

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Also use native Swift objects when available instead of their Foundation counterparts (such as `NSDictionary`, `NSMutableURLRequest`).

You should also use the `sender` option of `performSegue` to send the `json` data to your other view controller instead of storing it in another variable unless you use the `json` object in your first view controller as well.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SecondVCSegue"{
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SecondVC, let json = sender as? [String:Any] {
            destination.passedData = json
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What I need to define on secondVC?

Comment: Nothing, if `passedData` is already declared as `[String:Any]`. If it is not, just change it to have type `[String:Any]`. Other than that you just need to set up the manual segue in `Storyboard`.

Comment: I got 3 error when I use this code. 1.(let task = ...) Ambigous reference to member 'dataTask'(with:completion handler:)  2.  (guard let error...) Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer. 3. (if let json...) Expected expression in list of expressions

Comment: My bad, there were some typos, check it now