# Set up number of rows from passed JSON data in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview

I passed a JSON data to this table view controller. How to set up the number of rows from JSON data? How to define..

print(passedData), output:

```
["jobs": <__NSArrayM 0x17005d9d0>({
jobDate = "2017-08-31";
jobEndTime = 1504144800;
jobID = 87;
jobTime = 1504137600;}), 
"result": success, "message": Retrieve Sucessfully]
```

My code

```
var passedData: [String: Any]!

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //jobs.count
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let row : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell();
 //Add every Row
 return row;       
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the contents of your dictionary using the "jobs" key.

```
var jobIDs = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let jobs = passedData["jobs"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return }
    for job in jobs {
        if let idString = job["jobID"] as? String, let id = Int(idString) {
            jobIDs.append(id)
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return jobIDs.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = UITableViewCell()
     cell.textLabel.text = "\(jobIDs[indexPath.row])"
     return cell
 }
```

If you want to use the data from the `passedData` dictionary, it would make sense to do the parsing in a separate function so you can use the parsed results in all `UITableViewDataSource` functions. Using this approach you might want to call `tableView.reloadData()` at the end of the parsing function.

Comment: how to display jobID on every row?

Comment: @WanJern check my updated answer. Using it you can display the jobID on the label of each cell

Comment: Thanks! I tried the new method. The jobIDs.count seem not working. Because no any row showing...

Comment: Did you check if the parsing is working as expected? In `viewDidLoad` try to print `jobIDs.count` and if it is `nil`, use the debugger to see what is not working as expected.

Comment: I get zero, why?

Comment: Use the debugger to check what might go wrong. Is `jobs.count` non zero? Is the `if clause` ever reached?

Comment: jobIDs.count get zero, jobs.count get two

Comment: Please do `print(jobs.first)` just after `guard let jobs...` and include it in the question.

Comment: jobs.first get: Optional(["jobTime": 1504746000, "jobEndTime": 1504749600, "jobID": 104, "jobDate": 2017-09-07])

Comment: I'm still using the old code to get the data from server. so jobs.first is getting optional or [ ]. Is that the reason I can't get jobIDs.count? and I changed the flow. Last time I will retrieve the data on first VC then pass it to second VC. but now I will pass the jobDateValue to second VC then I retrieve data on second VC. but I think the method to display data on each cell is same. old code:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955853/passing-json-data-from-http-request-to-another-view-controller-in-swift-3

Comment: Check my updated answer, I have included some debugging instructions.

Comment: Xcode auto correct job to jobs and I can only print (jobs), others i get this error : Cannot subscript a value of type [[String:Any]] with an index of type 'String'

Comment: You don't have to use the autocomplete results... I cannot really help you figure out the problem is you can't figure out how to use Xcode itself.

Comment: Then you are definitely not using the code in my answer. You should put the print statements inside the for loop, only inside which `job` is defined.

Comment: Opps... sorry. only as Int is getting nil. other print got the correct result. Optional(105), nil and Optional("105")

Comment: Check my updated answer. It seems you first need to cast it to String, then to Int. If you don't really need an Int, you can just store the String and display that on the UI.

Comment: It works! thanks! but how if I want to display jobTime-jobEndTime? It's not Int? because I got zero when I put "if let idString = job["jobTime"] as? String.."

Comment: Parse it to Int. And look into how to work with dictionaries + how to parse JSON. If you really can't get along, ask a new question, since this is not really about the original question anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help!

```
var passedData: [String: Any]!

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//jobs.count
    if let jobs = passedData["jobs"] as? [[String:Any]] {
         return jobs.count
    }
    return 0
}
```